# Wifi Management on XP (SP2/SP3)

Tags: wifi, windows-xp

Wifi support on Vista is fine, but [Native Wifi on XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204766.aspx) is half baked. [NDIS 802.11 Wireless LAN Miniport Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa504121.aspx) only gets you part of the way there (e.g. network scanning). From what I've read (and tried), the 802.11 NDIS drivers on XP will *not* allow you to configure a wireless connection. You have to use the Native Wifi API in order to do this. (Please, correct me if I'm wrong here.) Applications like [InSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider) have helped me to understand the APIs, but InSSIDer is just a scanner and is not designed to configure Wifi networks.

So, the question is: where can I find some code examples (C# or C++) that deal with the configuration of Wifi networks on XP -- e.g. profile creation and connection management?

I should note that this is a XP Embedded application on a closed system where we can't use the built-in Wireless Zero Configuration (WZC). We have to build all Wifi management functionality into our .NET application.

Yes, I've Googled myself blue. It seems that someone should have a solution to this problem, but I can't find it. That's why I'm asking here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We use WZC on XP and Native WiFi on Vista, but here's the code which we use on Vista, FWIW.

Profile creation:

```
// open a handle to the service
if ((dwError = WlanOpenHandle(
        WLAN_API_VERSION,
        NULL,               // reserved
        &dwServiceVersion,
        &hClient
        )) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
hClient = NULL;
}
return dwError;
dwError=WlanSetProfile(hClient, &guid, 0, profile, NULL, TRUE, NULL, &reason_code);
```

Make a connection:

```
    WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS conn;

    conn.wlanConnectionMode=wlan_connection_mode_profile;
    conn.strProfile=name;
    conn.pDot11Ssid=NULL;
    conn.pDesiredBssidList=NULL;
    conn.dot11BssType=dot11_BSS_type_independent;
    conn.dwFlags=NULL;

    dwError = WlanConnect(hClient, &guid, &conn, NULL);
```

Check for connection:

```
    BOOL ret=FALSE;
    DWORD dwError;
    DWORD size;
    void *p=NULL;
    WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE *ps;

    dwError = WlanQueryInterface(hClient, &guid, wlan_intf_opcode_interface_state, NULL, &size, &p, NULL);
    ps=(WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE *)p;
    if(dwError!=0) 
        ret=FALSE;
    else
        if(*ps==wlan_interface_state_connected) 
            ret=TRUE;
    if(p!=NULL) WlanFreeMemory(p);
    return ret;
```

To keep connected to the network, just spawn a thread then keep checking for a connection, then re-connecting if need be.

EDIT: Man this markup stuff is lame.  Takes me like 3 edits to get the farking thing right.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback Nick. I've pretty much gotten the profile and connection management working. The trick is figuring out which parts of the Native Wifi API are **not** supported on XP.  Fortunately, the [Managed Wifi API](http://www.codeplex.com/managedwifi) has connect/disconnect notification events that do work on XP ([NetworkChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) also gives similar change events).